# Wordpress gallery image link gives 404 when not logged in

Tags: admin, attachments, gallery, 404-error

I'm attempting to use the default Wordpress gallery (from the post editor '`Add Media`' then '`Create Gallery`').

When logged in as an admin and clicking an image in the gallery on the resulting blog page will correctly link to the attachment page for the clicked image.

However when logged out, clicking an image in the gallery will result in a 404.

The URL is the same in both cases (something like `<my_wordpress_site>.com?attachment_id=2408`)

What could be causing this, and is there a way this could be fixed, so the attachment url loads correctly when logged out?

Comment: Is the post/page which the image is attached to definitely published? (i.e. not a draft or private)

Comment: it's definiteyly published. The post is viewable when not logged in.

Comment: I would first rule out a trouble making plugin. De-activate *all* of them, repeat the process (new post, upload & insert, publish) & see if the problem persists.